# Spark Streaming failing due to error on a different Kafka topic than the one being read

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

For the following write topic/read topic `air2008rand` tandem :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
(spark.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("subscribe", "air2008rand")
.load()
.groupBy('value.cast("string").as('key))
.agg(count("*").cast("string") as 'value)
.writeStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("includeTimestamp", true)
.option("topic","t1")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 seconds"))
.outputMode("update")
.option("checkpointLocation","/tmp/cp")
.start)
```

There is an error generated due to a  a *different* topic `air2008m1-0`:

```
scala> 19/07/14 13:27:22 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 711d44b2-3224-4493-8677-e5c8cc4f3db4, runId = 68a3519a-e9cf-4a82-9d96-99be833227c0] 
terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Set(air2008m1-0) are gone. 
Some data may have been missed.
Some data may have been lost because they are not available in Kafka any more; either the
 data was aged out by Kafka or the topic may have been deleted before all the data in the
 topic was processed. If you don't want your streaming query to fail on such cases, set the
 source option "failOnDataLoss" to "false".
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaMicroBatchReader$$reportDataLoss(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader.planInputPartitions(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.partitions$lzycompute(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.partitions(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.outputPartitioning(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:65)
```

This behavior is repeatable by stopping the read/write code (in spark-shell `repl`) and then re-running it.

Why is there "cross-talk" between different kafka topics here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to a checkpoint directory containing data from an earlier  spark streaming operation. The resolution is to change the checkpoint directory.

The solution was found as a comment (from @jaceklaskowski himself) in this question [[IllegalStateException]: Spark Structured Streaming is termination Streaming Query with Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864003/illegalstateexception-spark-structured-streaming-is-termination-streaming-que?rq=1)